# Web browsers ignoring max-width property in percents for table cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

Why are web browsers ignoring the `max-width` property in percents and apply the `max-width` property in px for table cells?

For example:

```
<td style="max-width:10%;word-wrap:break-word;">veryLongTextWithoutSpace</td>
```

will be ignored, and table cell content will not wrap.

But,

```
<td style="max-width=60px;word-wrap:break-word;">veryLongTextWithoutSpace</td>
```

will be applied and table cell content is wrapping.

UPD: More about my case and `table-layout: fixed`

`table-layout: fixed` with sets width to table header (th tags) it's real good [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/NuqzK/).
But, unfortunately, my case is crazy.

The table generates by custom tag (uses jsp technics), and I can't set the style for the table header (`th` tags), but I can set the style for each row and column.

At result, `table-layout: fixed` sets all columns with same width.

Full Example: http://jsfiddle.net/h3cxc/1/  (without `table-layout:fixed`)

http://jsfiddle.net/h3cxc/    (with `table-layout:fixed`)

Any idea how to fix this issue (max-width in percents) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your second example has a typo/error and can't possibly work since you are using = instead of : .

On to the question:

Add `table-layout:fixed` to your `table`.

> With this (fast) algorithm, the horizontal layout of the table does
>   not depend on the contents of the
>   cells; it only depends on the table's
>   width, the width of the columns, and
>   borders or cell spacing.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#propdef-table-layout

Check sample: http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/UuVq6/9/

Comment: Easwee, thanks for the answer.
But `table-layout:fixed` is not good case for me.
Table has column with equals width after applying this style, but I must have first column with minimal width (column contains simple checkbox without text). Also  it be good when I can set different width for different columns.
Besides I can't change styles for table header (th tag).
New sample: http://jsfiddle.net/h3cxc/